# Inner objects in my array of objects are not grouped correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This is the API in question:

```
        [Authorize(Roles = "manager")]
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomerSalesTargetChart()
        {
            var targets = await _requestPackage.Context.CustomerFamilyTarget
                    .Include(cft => cft.Customer)
                    .Include(cft => cft.Class_1)
                    .ToDictionaryAsync(cft => cft.CustomerId + " " + cft.Class_1ID, cft => cft.Target);

            var customerSalesTargets = await _requestPackage.Context.UserCustomerSalesTargets
                .Select(cst => new
                {
                    CustomerCode = cst.Customer.Code,
                    CustomerName = cst.Customer.Name,
                    SaleRepId = cst.ApplicationUser.Id,
                    SaleRepCode = cst.ApplicationUser.Code,
                    Families = cst.Class_1.Products.Select(cp => new
                    {
                        Id = cp.Class_1.Id,
                        ClassName = cp.Class_1.ClassName,
                        Code = cp.Class_1.Code,
                        Target = targets.ContainsKey(cst.Id + " " + cp.Class_1.Id) ? targets[cst.Id + " " + cp.Class_1.Id] : 0.0

                    }).Distinct().ToList(),
                    Year = cst.Year,
                    Month = cst.Month,
                    Sales = cst.Sales
                })
                .ToListAsync();

            return Ok(customerSalesTargets);

        }
```

The Response body:

```
[
  {
    "CustomerCode": "AAAAAAAAAA",
    "CustomerName": "Customer A",
    "SaleRepId": "1111111111111",
    "SaleRepCode": "141",
    "Families": [
      {
        "Id": 8,
        "ClassName": "Home Appliances",
        "Code": "107",
        "Target": 0
      }
    ],
    "Year": 2021,
    "Month": 6,
    "Sales": 9999
  },
  {
    "CustomerCode": "AAAAAAAAAA",
    "CustomerName": "Customer A",
    "SaleRepId": "1111111111111",
    "SaleRepCode": "141",
    "Families": [
      {
        "Id": 24,
        "ClassName": "Home Entertainment",
        "Code": "130",
        "Target": 0
      }
    ],
    "Year": 2021,
    "Month": 6,
    "Sales": 9999
  },
  {
    "CustomerCode": "AAAAAAAAAA",
    "CustomerName": "Customer A",
    "SaleRepId": "1111111111111",
    "SaleRepCode": "141",
    "Families": [
      {
        "Id": 24,
        "ClassName": "Home Entertainment",
        "Code": "130",
        "Target": 0
      }
    ],
    "Year": 2021,
    "Month": 5,
    "Sales": 9999
  },
  {
    "CustomerCode": "BBBBBBBBBB",
    "CustomerName": "Customer B",
    "SaleRepId": "1111111111111",
    "SaleRepCode": "141",
    "Families": [
      {
        "Id": 4,
        "ClassName": "Gaming",
        "Code": "103",
        "Target": 0
      }
    ],
    "Year": 2021,
    "Month": 6,
    "Sales": 9999
  }
]
```

I want the response body to look like this instead:

```
[
  {
    "CustomerCode": "AAAAAAAAAA",
    "CustomerName": "Customer A",
    "SaleRepId": "1111111111111",
    "SaleRepCode": "141",
    "Families": [
      {
        "Id": 8,
        "ClassName": "Home Appliances",
        "Code": "107",
        "Target": 0
      },
      {
        "Id": 24,
        "ClassName": "Home Entertainment",
        "Code": "130",
        "Target": 0
      },
    ],
    "Year": 2021,
    "Month": 6,
    "Sales": 9999
  },
  {
    "CustomerCode": "AAAAAAAAAA",
    "CustomerName": "Customer A",
    "SaleRepId": "1111111111111",
    "SaleRepCode": "141",
    "Families": [
      {
        "Id": 24,
        "ClassName": "Home Entertainment",
        "Code": "130",
        "Target": 0
      }
    ],
    "Year": 2021,
    "Month": 5,
    "Sales": 9999
  },
  {
    "CustomerCode": "BBBBBBBBBB",
    "CustomerName": "Customer B",
    "SaleRepId": "1111111111111",
    "SaleRepCode": "141",
    "Families": [
      {
        "Id": 4,
        "ClassName": "Gaming",
        "Code": "103",
        "Target": 0
      }
    ],
    "Year": 2021,
    "Month": 6,
    "Sales": 9999
  }
]
```

I want to group the objects by family and by month, where if the same customer had sales in the same month, for different families, those will be within the same customer object.

But if the sale was for a different month, it should be separated alone.

Comment: I guess we'll need some info about your db-model to solve this one. There is obviously something with this part of your code: `Families = cst.Class_1.Products.Select`

Comment: I am guessing before doing this `_requestPackage.Context.UserCustomerSalesTargets.Select`, you might need to group `UserCustomerSalesTargets` by the `Month` property.

Comment: Can you share the related table structure and the initial data (such as the CustomerFamilyTarget table, Customer table, Class_1 table  and UserCustomerSalesTargets table etc.)? So that we can reproduce the problem on our side. Besides, in the inner query statement (`cst.Class_1.Products.Select`), try to use a where clause to filter data, it should get all related Families.

Comment: @AmitDash You are correct. I contacted a senior friend and they helped, I needed to use the GroupBy method on my DbSet, creating a `Key` object, and then nest my `Families` inner object as `Data` for the `Key`. Giving me the result I want.

Comment: Good to hear that, cheers :)

Comment: @ZhiLv The structure of `UserCustomerSalesTargets` is exactly my output objects, except for `CustomerName` and `ClassName` which are pulled from `Customer` model and `Class_1` model respectively. `CustomerFamilyTarget` is a simple join between `Customer` table and `Class_1` model, it represents a new table giving a `Target` field for them.

Comment: @AmitDash Should I post my new code as an answer?

Comment: Sure please go ahead, post it as an answer which will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AmitDash noted, I needed to utilize the `GroupBy` method on my `DbSet` to achieve the "Object within Object" goal I needed.

And this is my new API:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "manager")]
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public async Task<List<object>> GetCustomerSalesTargetChart()
        {
            var customerFamiliesModelList = new List<object>();

            var targets = await _requestPackage.Context.CustomerFamilyTarget
                .Include(cft => cft.Customer)
                .Include(cft => cft.Class_1)
                .ToDictionaryAsync(cft => cft.CustomerId + " " + cft.Class_1ID, cft => cft.Target);

            var userCustomerSalesTargets = await _requestPackage.Context.UserCustomerSalesTargets
                .Include(ucst => ucst.ApplicationUser)
                .Include(ucst => ucst.Class_1)
                .Include(ucst => ucst.Customer)
                .GroupBy(ucst => new { customerId = ucst.CustomerId, saleRep = ucst.ApplicationUserId, month = ucst.Month, year = ucst.Year })
                .Select(ucst => new { Key = ucst.Key, Data = ucst.ToList() })
                .ToListAsync();


            var userCustomerSalesTargetsObj = userCustomerSalesTargets.Select(cst => new
            {
                CustomerCode = cst.Data.FirstOrDefault().CustomerCode,
                CuustomerName = cst.Data.FirstOrDefault().Customer.Name,
                SaleRepId = cst.Key.saleRep,
                SaleRepCode = cst.Data.FirstOrDefault().ApplicationUser.Code,
                Familis = cst.Data.Select(d => new
                {
                    Id = d.Class_1.Id,
                    ClassName = d.Class_1.ClassName,
                    Code = d.Class_1.Code,
                    Target = targets.ContainsKey(cst.Key.customerId + " " + d.Class_1.Id) ? targets[cst.Key.customerId + " " + d.Class_1.Id] : 0.0
                }).ToList(),
                Year = cst.Key.year,
                Month = cst.Key.month,
                Sales = cst.Data.FirstOrDefault().Sales
            }).ToList();

            customerFamiliesModelList.Add(userCustomerSalesTargetsObj);

            return customerFamiliesModelList;
        }
```

Here's the breakdown of what I did:
`var customerFamiliesModelList = new List<object>();` is list object which will be the final format of my response object body.

Here:

```
var targets = await _requestPackage.Context.CustomerFamilyTarget
    .Include(cft => cft.Customer)
    .Include(cft => cft.Class_1)
    .ToDictionaryAsync(cft => cft.CustomerId + " " + cft.Class_1ID, cft => cft.Target);
```

I pulled my `Target` data member from `CustomerFamilyTarget` model, and arranged it in a dictionary along with the `CustomerId` and `Class_1ID`.

Here:

```
var userCustomerSalesTargets = await _requestPackage.Context.UserCustomerSalesTargets
    .Include(ucst => ucst.ApplicationUser)
    .Include(ucst => ucst.Class_1)
    .Include(ucst => ucst.Customer)
    .GroupBy(ucst => new { customerId = ucst.CustomerId, saleRep = ucst.ApplicationUserId, month = ucst.Month, year = ucst.Year })
    .Select(ucst => new { Key = ucst.Key, Data = ucst.ToList() })
    .ToListAsync();
```

This is like the shape of my final object, where I included the necessary models from `UserCustomerSalesTargets`, then I used `GroupBy` to create a `Key` Object. So, everything inside the `GroupBy` *is* a `Key` in its own right.
And then in the `.Select` method, we stated how we want our final object to look like `Key` -> `Data`.

Here:

```
var userCustomerSalesTargetsObj = userCustomerSalesTargets.Select(cst => new
{
    CustomerCode = cst.Data.FirstOrDefault().CustomerCode,
    CuustomerName = cst.Data.FirstOrDefault().Customer.Name,
    SaleRepId = cst.Key.saleRep,
    SaleRepCode = cst.Data.FirstOrDefault().ApplicationUser.Code,
    Familis = cst.Data.Select(d => new
    {
        Id = d.Class_1.Id,
        ClassName = d.Class_1.ClassName,
        Code = d.Class_1.Code,
        Target = targets.ContainsKey(cst.Key.customerId + " " + d.Class_1.Id) ? targets[cst.Key.customerId + " " + d.Class_1.Id] : 0.0
     }).ToList(),
     Year = cst.Key.year,
     Month = cst.Key.month,
     Sales = cst.Data.FirstOrDefault().Sales
}).ToList();
```

I specified what I want to put inside my object, so here for example `CustomerCode = cst.Data.FirstOrDefault().CustomerCode,` I pulled the `CustomerCode` from the `Data` part of my object. But here `SaleRepId = cst.Key.saleRep,` I pulled `saleRep` from the `Key` part of my object.
Here:

```
Familis = cst.Data.Select(d => new
{
   Id = d.Class_1.Id,
   ClassName = d.Class_1.ClassName,
   Code = d.Class_1.Code,
   Target = targets.ContainsKey(cst.Key.customerId + " " + d.Class_1.Id) ? targets[cst.Key.customerId + " " + d.Class_1.Id] : 0.0
}).ToList(),
```

I just created the "inner" (I don't know what else to call it) object, of my "outter" object.

Here's how my final object looks like:

```
[
  [
    {
      "CustomerCode": "AAAAAAAAAAA",
      "CuustomerName": "Customer A",
      "SaleRepId": "11111111111111",
      "SaleRepCode": "141",
      "Familis": [
        {
          "Id": 4,
          "ClassName": "Gaming",
          "Code": "103",
          "Target": 0
        }
      ],
      "Year": 2021,
      "Month": 5,
      "Sales": 466662
    },
    {
      "CustomerCode": "AAAAAAAAAAA",
      "CuustomerName": "Customer A",
      "SaleRepId": "11111111111111",
      "SaleRepCode": "141",
      "Familis": [
        {
          "Id": 8,
          "ClassName": "Home Appliances",
          "Code": "107",
          "Target": 4000
        },
        {
          "Id": 24,
          "ClassName": "Home Entertainment",
          "Code": "130",
          "Target": 2000
        }
      ],
      "Year": 2021,
      "Month": 6,
      "Sales": 14000
    },
    {
      "CustomerCode": "BBBBBBBBBBB",
      "CuustomerName": "Customer B",
      "SaleRepId": "11111111111111",
      "SaleRepCode": "141",
      "Familis": [
        {
          "Id": 24,
          "ClassName": "Home Entertainment",
          "Code": "130",
          "Target": 0
        }
      ],
      "Year": 2021,
      "Month": 6,
      "Sales": 4555
    }
  ]
]
```